# How to show special character in Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Will Increase Font Size will work here?

Current view:
[image]

Now, I want to load special character in the same `staggered View` in the place of Images.
special Icons are i.e.

`( .o.)  , ( ° ͜ ʖ °), ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)` and e.t.c.

## Questions

- How can I increase the size of each of these special characters. So that they will look similar to current staggered view Images?
- What would be the good approach to achieve this task?
- If I increase the `Font Size` then it will not behave as `Staggered Grid View`

I am achieving something similar to this:

[image]

This is just the one image but in similar fashion I wanted to upload all other special character in `staggered View`

Edit-1

I just passed the special character to `GridVeiw.TextView` and I got this:

[image]

Size of icons are still smalls

Comment: You can use font icons. Every character refers to one special icon and you can change their font size. Check this : https://icomoon.io

Comment: @icmoon These are not icons, These are just special keyword coming from Json

Comment: @Def I have been using Font Icons for a while and never had a problem related different screen sizes. Font Icons are vektor and you can arrange their densities according to other screen sizes. Also you can check this link too: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/08/use-font-awesome-glyph-icons-android/

Comment: @Def Just convert your special characters to your wanted shape/special char as a Font icon. This will work. I tried this with a little similar case.

Comment: @Frank Actually I am getting these data through Json. Sorry I am not getting you

Comment: @oguzhand Checkout the Edit-1 section

Comment: @Def, please share code: how do you put special character, share layout and json

Comment: @LaurentY It's not completed yet. I will share it once it's done!

Comment: @guys I asked a question related to this post. Please have a look at the new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217609/how-to-handle-ascii-character-in-android-layout