# How to handle Ascii character in Android Layout

Tags: java, android, ascii, ascii-art

Related [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214391/how-to-show-special-character-in-android-layout)

I do have to show different `Ascii` character in `TextView`. Character are:

```
( `·´ )

(\\/)(°,,,°)(\\/)

( ⚆ _ ⚆ )
```

If I used above character and display on screen. I got this:
[image]

But when you look at the first `character`. It's displaying the wrong image. It supposed to be like this:

[image]

I have never worked on `Ascii character` like this.

## Question

How can I handle these type of situations? Is there any libraries exist?

Any help would be appreciable.

Edit-1

## layout file

Layout file is a `GridView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/img_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show you XML does the textView has multiLine true ?

Comment: @PedroAGSantos Just pasted the layout file

Comment: You can easily replace `)(` with `)\n(`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to use newlines (**`\n`**).

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="(\\/)\n(°,,,°)\n(\\/)"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: @hata Is this generic solution. I mean what you will do when you have to multiple `Ascii` characters?

I mean to say when you will decide when you have to add "\n" because I am getting this data through Json response

Comment: @Def If the JSON response itself doesn't contain `\n` or any other line delimiters, I don't think you can know that.